# JQuery UI slider not work inside fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox, jquery-ui-slider

I try to put slide bar inside jquery fancybox popup but some events like mouseup, mouseover not work. But if I put slider div outside fancybox popup, if work normally. So how can I fix this problem? Appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using:

```
.live('mouseup', function() {

.live('mouseover', function() {
```

instead of:

```
.mouseup(function() {

.mouseover(function() {
```

as the content inside fancybox is created dynamically.

You could also put your slider initialization code inside of the fancybox `onComplete` function. See [fancybox.net/api](http://fancybox.net/api)

Comment: Hi Samuel Liew, thank for your help but I have a problem: I can't control these events, Jquery UI Slider working with jquery.ui.core, jquery.ui.mouse and jquery.ui.widget. I have tried to change handle events code in jquery.ui.slider but it not work success

Comment: @Nguyen please check this answer as accepted, to help us. It gives both you and Samuel rep and saves others time from looking at a question that we don't think has been answered. Thanks!